# Inheritance with templates

Tags: class, templates, inheritance, radix

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

class C
 {
public:
C (){};
virtual void nothing()=0;
virtual ~C (){};
 };

class A : public C
{
public:
 A (){};
 virtual void nothing(){};
};
class B:public A 
{
public:
 B(){};
 void nothing(){};
};

template <class T>
void hi(T){
cout << " i am something\n";
}

template <>
void hi<A>(A)
{
cout << " I am A\n";
}

template <>
void hi<B>(B)
{
cout << " I am B\n";
}

int main ( ) 
{
C *array [] = {new A,new B};
hi (*array [0]);
hi (*array [1]);

delete array [0];
delete array [1];
return 0; 

}
```

Out: 
i am something
I am something

Currently I am writing a program that has to deal with
Inherited types and specialised templates. In the example above I would l would like to see 
I am A
I am B
Is there a way to properly invoke the functions corresponding to the objects although I am handling a base class array? I am not sure if type checking and conversion via dynamic_cast is the most elegant solution. Note that this is just an excerpt from a larger program.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You're trying to use your objects polymorphically, but template instantiation happens at compile time. You need runtime type checking, just as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main routine, the three lines shown below create an array of `C*`.
So any element of that array is treated as a `C*` regardless of 
what the actual type of the element is.
That is, when you pass `*array [0]` to the function `hi()`,
the function that gets called is `hi(C)` which resolves to
the generic `hi` function, not either of the specialized functions.

```
C *array [] = {new A,new B};
hi (*array [0]);
hi (*array [1]);
```

In order to make `hi<A>` be invoked, you either have to store the pointer
to the new object in a variable of type `A*` or you need to cast the
`C*` to an `A*`.

In a case like this, a virtual function of `C`, overridden in `A` and `B`,
may serve the purpose better.